# Migrating Node JS code to Apollo server

Tags: node.js, express, graphql, apollo

I am setting up Apollo Server on my Node app and wondered about moving the functionality over to Apollo.

I have business logic like this:

```
router.post(
    '/login',
    (req, res, next) => {
        if (!req.body.email || !req.body.password) {
            return 'You must send the username and the password.';
        }
        Users.findOne({ email: req.body.email })
            .then(user => {
                bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password, (err, success) => {
                    req.user = user;
                    next();
                });
            })
    },
    auth.createToken,
    auth.createRefreshToken,
    auth.logUserActivity,
    (req, res) => {
        res.status(201).send({
            success: true,
            authToken: req.authToken,
            refreshToken: req.refreshToken
        });
    }
);
```

It follows Node router architecture where I add the found `user` object to `req` object, which passes the user to the next functions - `createToken` etc.. using the `next()` function. This was ok for my server before trying to introduce GraphQL/Apollo, but now I want all this logic to be easily accessible to the Apollo resolvers.

I often hear that people are having an easy time turning their server from REST/non-GraphQL  into a GraphQL server, but at the moment it's looking like it's going to be a bit of a job to go through all the logic and separate everything in to their own functions which take parameters directly rather than using the `req` object.

Is this a correct assumption? Or am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating the code you have shown above would be a very easy task. Once you build your graphql server and create your schema, etc. Then all you need to do is create login mutation. Then your resolver would handle the logic you have shown above. Then, instead of pulling the values from from req.body they would be function parameters.

A good pattern I am currently following is creating a login method on the model itself. Then the resolver calls the method on the schema (Here is an example of a project I'm doing it on now: [Login method](https://github.com/knipferrc/fitme-api/blob/master/methods/userMethods.js). Then here is an example of what the resolver looks like: [Resolver](https://github.com/knipferrc/fitme-api/blob/master/mutations/login.js)

Hopefully that helped!